# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre préstamo lingüístico y extranjerismo?

Tags: lingüística

La RAE define *extranjerismo* y *préstamo* como:

> [**extranjerismo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOauPO6)
>   (...)
>   2. m. Ling. Préstamo, especialmente el no adaptado.

y

> [**préstamo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U73g6MY)
>   (...)
>   4. m. Ling. Elemento, generalmente léxico, que una lengua toma de otra.

Luego comenta Fundéu en [extranjerismo o préstamo lingüístico](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/extranjerismo-o-prestamo-linguistico-2168/):

> Normalmente, se entiende que los extranjerismos son las palabras o construcciones extranjeras (*barman*) mientras que los préstamos son palabras que tienen su origen en otras lenguas (*azúcar* es un préstamo del árabe).

Pero la lectura de sendos artículos ([extranjerismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extranjerismo) y [préstamo lingüístico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9stamo_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstico)) en la Wikipedia me confunde. Por ejemplo, menciona *fútbol* (del inglés *football*) como extranjerismo del tipo de préstamo léxico. ¿Pero no parecía por lo dicho por Fundéu que la línea divisoria entre unos y otros es su adaptación?

Es por ello que me pregunto: ¿alguien podría indicar cuál es la línea divisoria entre ellos, si la hay, o si extranjerismo es un subtipo de préstamo lingüístico?

La RAE me [indicó por Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/768074489628397570) que:

> Algunos especialistas llaman «extranjerismo» al no adaptado y reservan el término «préstamo» para las adaptaciones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde un marco de teoría lingüística, esto es como preguntar cuál es la diferencia entre lengua y dialecto.  En realidad no existe una demarcación nítida; todo criterio que apliquemos, al examinarse de cerca, resulta ser vago y arbitrario.

Desde un punto de vista práctico, sin embargo, existen criterios bastante útiles para juzgar a cuál grado un vocablo de origen extranjero se ha adaptado a la lengua.  Por ejemplo:

- ¿Tiene el vocablo sentido diferente en español que en la lengua de origen?

  - Esto es un índice de *norma divergente*—los hispanohablantes han adaptado una norma de uso del vocablo que es independiente de la lengua de origen.
- ¿Es común el vocablo entre hispanohablantes monolingües, o sólo entre bilingües?

  - Si es común entre monolingües entonces tenemos transmisión del vocablo independiente del conocimiento de la lengua extranjera.
- ¿Cuántos hablantes conocen el origen extranjero del vocablo?

  - Si son muy pocos, especialmente entre los hablantes cultos, es un índice de adaptación al español.
- La fonología y fonotáctica del vocablo, ¿se parecen más a la gramática española o a la de la lengua de origen?

  - Ejemplo: *bibaporú* (cuya fuente es *Vicks' VapoRub*) es netamente español en su fonología (e.g., reemplazo de /v/ por /b/) y fonotáctica (eliminación de la coda silábica compleja de *Vicks'*, que no conforma con el español).
- Los hablantes nativos de la lengua de origen, ¿reconocen el vocablo cuando lo encuentran en español?  (*Bibaporú* es un gran ejemplo.)
- ¿Existe un antiguo sinónimo nativo del vocablo, o denota éste un nuevo concepto que entró a la cultura con el préstamo?  Ejemplo: [cuark](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark)

  - Especialmente cuando se trata de temas científicos o técnicos, los inventos muchas veces los hacen extranjeros y su vocabulario se toma o calca al español.

Cabe reafirmar que estos criterios son vagos y arbitrarios; no nos dicen "la verdad" de la lengua, sino que nos ayudan a tomar decisiones prácticas, como cuáles palabras incluir en un diccionario.  Y cabe también añadir que es español es una lengua pluricéntrica, hablada en 21 países cuyas normas lingüísticas no coinciden, así que la respuesta que dan estos criterios y otros parecidos muchas veces dependen del país or dialecto al cual los apliquemos.

Comment: La expuesta y el desarrollo analítico es de gran certeza -- excelente trabajo.

Answer (score 3):

La Wikipedia es una gran herramienta, pero no debemos tomarla nunca como una fuente infalible de conocimiento, especialmente si el artículo no tiene referencias fiables o acreditadas.

Si te fijas, en ambos artículos existe una clasificación de extranjerismos/préstamos, según las cuales uno pertenece al otro. Lo cual carece de sentido.

Buscando un poco, puede verse lo que dice la RAE sobre [extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/publicaciones/25-extranjerismos). En este otro [enlace](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos) se explaya un poco más. Pero en ninguno de los dos nombra a los préstamos lingüísticos, y no he sido capaz de encontrar nada al respecto.

Basándome en lo que aquí se explica, y en las dos definiciones que has puesto del DRAE, entiendo que extranjerismo es un concepto más genérico, y que los préstamos son un tipo de extranjerismo adaptado y no superfluo.

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia es que los extranjerismos se transfiere sin ningún tipo de cambio y el préstamo lingüístico adapta la palabra y cambia algunas cosas
**strong text**