# ¿Se consideran extranjerismos los significados o matices añadidos por influencia de otros idiomas a palabras que ya existían en español?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, extranjerismos

Ya en otras preguntas del sitio se han comentado casos de otras palabras que, debido a influencias de idiomas extranjeros, acaban adoptando significados diferentes de los que tenían previamente en español. Ejemplos:

- [Eventualmente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16380/12637). Se usa con el significado de "antes o después" en vez de con el significado de "incierta o casualmente" por influjo del inglés.
- [Bizarro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17074/12637). Se usa con el significado de "raro" en vez de "valiente" por influjo del francés, italiano y otros.

Yo entiendo estos casos como pequeños detalles que atestiguan un proceso mayor: el de la fusión de idiomas. Si se ve con perspectiva, el mundo en el que vivimos hace cada vez más fácil aprender y usar otros idiomas, nos acerca unos a otros, y las palabras y significados entran en un proceso de fusión semántica por pura comodidad del hablante. Se hace patente últimamente en el caso de *[condescender](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22290/12637)*, que está introduciendo en español la carga negativa que tiene en inglés.

Estos procesos de modificación semántica de palabras ya existentes en castellano, ¿se consideran extranjerismos? A mi entender, un extranjerismo es una palabra que se ha introducido en el idioma a falta de una alternativa apropiada, y que aún no se ha adaptado. Así lo recoge el DLE:

> **[extranjerismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOauPO6)**
>
> 2. m. *Ling.* Préstamo, especialmente el no adaptado.

Así, en su día *football* fue un extranjerismo hasta que se adaptó a *fútbol*. Y más recientes han sido el caso de *tweet* que se adaptó como *[tuit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asqoMGb)*, y el caso de *[manga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OBTib4V)* (como cómic japonés), que no precisó de adaptación.

Por su parte, el término "[préstamo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17741/12637)" en lingüística hace referencia a los elementos que unas lenguas toman de otras, pero suelen ser elementos léxicos y no semánticos.

En cambio, estos casos son diferentes, dado que las palabras ya existían con sus correspondientes significados y no han variado su escritura. Los préstamos lo que han hecho ha sido introducir nuevos significados. Y en algunos casos ni siquiera cambia el significado, solo introduce matices (como palabras que pasan a ser peyorativas). ¿Existe otro nombre para designar a estos casos?

Answer (score 2):

Yo diría que no, un extranjerismo como has indicado es un préstamo y un préstamo según el DLE es:

> [**préstamo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U73g6MY)
>
> 4. m. Ling. Elemento, generalmente léxico, que una lengua toma de otra

Pero hablamos de una palabra que ya existe en el idioma que la recibe y lo que hace es incluir un significado que no tenía.

Lo que está claro es que es un *calco semántico* y aunque eso no descarta que pueda ser también un extranjerismo yo diría que son cosas distintas.

> **[calco semántico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6kG5DDl)**
>
> 1. m. Ling. Adopción de un significado extranjero para una palabra ya existente en una lengua; p. ej., ratón, en su acepción 'aparato manual
>    conectado a una computadora', es calco semántico del inglés mouse.

Comment: Se me hace curioso el ejemplo que pone la RAE con _mouse_. En ambos idiomas _mouse/ratón_ es un animal y en ambos idiomas decidimos llamar al aparato electrónico de la misma forma. No veo que hayamos copiado/calcado una palabra del inglés sino que simplemente coincidimos en como llamar un nuevo aparato. ¿Si para el español es un "calco" entonces para el ingles sería un "auto-calco"? Definitivamente no. Ese ejemplo se me hace muy diferente al caso de _Bizarro_ que nos cuenta Carlos. En español frecuentemente le damos nuevos significados a palabras existentes sin que sea ningún calco.Ej: duro=$

Comment: @DGaleano No hemos calcado la palabra del inglés sino uno de sus significados a una palabra que ya tenemos

Comment: Eso es lo que se me hace curioso pues SI le dimos un nuevo significado a uno de nuestros sustantivos pero no se me hace que hayamos calcado ningún significado del inglés. Apareció un aparato nuevo y coincidimos en como llamarlo. Ellos también le dieron un nuevo significado a uno de sus sustantivos y eso no es nada extraordinario. Un **duro** = una **peseta**, perder la **chaveta** =perder la **cabeza** , etc. Estoy de acuerdo que los calcos semánticos existen pero creo que la RAE debería mejorar el ejemplo. En la pregunta hay dos buenos ejemplos. Es mejor el esfuerzo de Carlos que el de la RAE

Comment: No es casualidad que se le llame ratón en español, el nombre se le puso en inglés y lo copiamos. Por cierto un duro son cinco pesetas.

Comment: You say tomato I say to-mah-to :-)